# how to make a loop of a switch statement with a label in java

Tags: java, switch-statement, label

it's quite simple but i don't seem to fegure it out 
 here is my code

```
System.out.println("1=>do this \n2=> do that \n3=> blablabla \n4=> EXIT");


choose:{
int choix = s.nextInt();
switch (choix) {
case 1 : lper.addpersonne(); 
     break choose;
case 2 : lper.removepersonne();
     break choose;
case 3 : blalalalala
```

when it comes to execution

the "lper.addpersonne" works perfectly fine but after that i can't get the label where i can choose something else . it just stops

Comment: Any reason you don't use a typical looping structure as opposed to the label approach? Anyway, how do you expect it to display something outside its label body?

Comment: well for beginig i can't use "for" because i don't know how many times i'll have to choose
i tried while . but it keeps telling me "choix" is not defind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not clean that code up a bit and use something along these lines?

```
int choix;
do {

    System.out.println("1=>do this \n2=> do that \n3=> blablabla \n4=> EXIT");
    choix = s.nextInt();
    switch (choix) {
    case 1 : lper.addpersonne(); 
        break;
    case 2 : lper.removepersonne();
        break;
    case 3 : blalalalala
        break;

} while (choix != 4);
```

This way you don't have to worry about the `for` loop, it repeats until the user wants to quit, and you don't have to use the pesky labels.

Comment: Of course ... do while loop execute look for condition first and in first step choix is not defined yet :)

Comment: @IslamBouderbala, my bad, you have to move the declaration outside the do scope.

Comment: @SimeonPopov, actually a do while loop is guaranteed to run at least once. The reason is that the check is technically outside the scope ({...}) of the do-while, hence the cannot be resolved to a variable error.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean loop = true;
while(loop){    
System.out.println("1=>do this \n2=> do that \n3=> blablabla \n4=> EXIT");
choose:{
    int choix = s.nextInt();
    switch (choix) {
    case 1 : lper.addpersonne(); 
        break choose;
    case 2 : lper.removepersonne();
     break choose;
    case 3 : blalalalala
    .... //What do you want more
    }
if(choix == 4){loop = false;}
}
```

}

Comment: don't worry i puted the options in the loop again

Comment: Ok, i'm happy if i help you :)